# Java How do I create a module class that extends SimpleModule for addDeserializer?

Tags: java, module, jackson, objectmapper

Currently I am registering my class with a custom JsonDeserialize class with declaring a new SimpleModule in my app start, something like

```
public static void configure(ObjectMapperModule mapper) {
  SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
  module.addDeserializer(LocalFile.class, new LocalFileDeserializer());
  // module add more deserializer class
  mapper.registerModule(module);
}
```

Is there anyway that I can create a class that extends the SimpleModule, so I can register all class in the constructor maybe? I have tried below but it failed,

```
public class MyCustomModule extends SimpleModule {
    private static final SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();

    public MyCustomModule() {
        initMyCustomModule();
    }

    final void initMyCustomModule() {
        module.addDeserializer(LocalFile.class, new LocalFileDeserializer());
    }
}

// In app start
mapper.registerModule(new MyCustomModule());
```

I have seen the `initMyCustomModule` was being called during app start but my deserialize class was not being called when tried to deserialize my object from request, I was thinking because I should register the module inside my class, e.g: mapper.registerModule(new MyCustomModule().module)? I also noticed there was a override method for

```
@Override
public void setupModule(SetupContext context)
```

but I am not sure how to use it to `addDeserializer` into the context...

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this works...I don't need to declare a new instance of SimpleModule and use that in constructor, I can directly use `addDeserializer` in my constructor..

```
public class MyCustomModule extends SimpleModule {
    public MyCustomModule() {
        initMyCustomModule();
    }

    final void initMyCustomModule() {
        addDeserializer(LocalFile.class, new LocalFileDeserializer());
    }
}
```